# git command with command substitution doesn't return anything

Tags: windows, git, bash, shell, sh

bash: `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(4)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)`
OS: `Windows7`
git: `git version 2.6.4.windows.1`

Without command substitution, directly executing git commands would return correct answers.

```
$ git write-tree
76cb4719e27c7d77ef396992b3ba90cd98d22fcd
```

But when I execute **some** git commands with command substitution, it would return nothing.

```
$ echo "`git write-tree`"

$ echo "$(git write-tree)"
```

But the most strange thing is: Only some of git commmands occur this problem, for example: `git write-tree`, `git rev-parse`,  `git var`. And other git commands, such as `git log`, run well.

And some environment is exactly as same as mine, OS, bash and git. But everything works fine.
As a result, I wanna konw whether there's something I need to configure. This thing really confuse me.

Comment: git-write-tree document says "Conceptually, git write-tree sync()s the current index contents into a set of tree files. In order to have that match what is actually in your directory right now, you need to have done a git update-index phase before you did the git write-tree." try giving git update-index and git write-tree

Answer (score 0):

That must have been fixed in more recent version of Git for Windows.
Here is what I see with Git 2.18, in a bash session:

```
vonc@vonca:/mnt/d/git/tests/aa$ echo $(git write-tree)
4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904

vonc@vonca:/mnt/d/git/tests/aa$ echo "$(git write-tree)"
4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
```

If the issue is still random, try making the same test using a [CMD session with a simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51941666/6309), and launching the bash from said session.